# Importing the same PHP class within multiple files of the same namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I would like to `Use` the same class `Helper`, located at `App\Helpers\Helper`, in two different files within the same namespace.

For example:

**Class A:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

Use Helper;

class A {...}
```

**Class B:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

Use Helper;

class B {...}
```

However, this is not allowed. The error is:

```
Cannot use App\Helpers\Helper as Helper because the name is already in use
```

I could rename the `Helper` class in my second file and say `Use Helper as SomethingElse`, but this seems like a messy solution especially if I want to use this `Helper` in many more than two classes.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I think the name of `helper` is too general, as for future debug purpose, it is better to specify a class name of what it does imho

Comment: Of course, I was merely using a general name so the question would be general. In my project I do not use the class name 'Helper'.

Comment: hmm, maybe combine the `helper` class and extends from it ? just throwing some ideas :S

Comment: There is only one helper class. I could extend, but that would seem even less semantically correct than just renaming it in each class. Thanks for the thought though.

Comment: is there any relationship between `A` and `B`?

Comment: @iroegbu, not necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably already have an included class that goes by that name, the likely problem is that you have a class by that name in another namespace (and said class has been included). You can use both classes (from different namespaces with the same name) by aliasing or using fully qualified names of the classes.
Read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) properly.

Comment: Thanks, but the question was how can I avoid that, if at all.

Comment: @tam I gave two options, qualify fully or use aliasing.

Comment: I am trying to use the same 'helper' class in both class A and class B, thus fully qualifying will not help. Using aliasing to rename the 'Helper' in one of the two classes would work, but I am hoping to avoid that if possible. I edited the question based off your comment to hopefully make it more clear, I see I was a bit ambiguous, thanks!